# Extracting Location and Value of Vector

Tags: r, if-statement

So I want to extract both the location and the value of a vector. Here is the example code:

```
x <- matrix(1:96, nrow = 8)
x
y <- c(0,8,0,0,0,7,0,0,0)
y
which(y > 0)
```

This gives and output of

```
[1] 2 6
```

I want to then find the values of `x[2,8]` and `x[6,7]`. I have tried to do:

```
test <- ifelse(y > 0, x[which(y > 0 ),y], 0)
```

But that only produces

```
[1]  0 62  0  0  0 62  0  0  0
```

Which is actually `x[6,8]`. There is probably a relatively easy way to do this in R and I am missing something fairly simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We create a row/column numeric index based on `which(y>0)` and `y[y>0]`, `cbind` it and use that to extract the values in 'x'

```
 x1 <- x[cbind(which(y>0), y[y>0])]
 x1 
 #[1] 58 54
```

If we want to replace the non-zero elements in 'y', use the condition `y>0` and replace those 'y' values with 'x1'.

```
 y[y>0] <- x1
 y
 #[1]  0 58  0  0  0 54  0  0  0
```

Or if we don't need to change the initial 'y' vector

```
 y1 <-  replace(y, which(y > 0), x1)
 y1
 #[1]  0 58  0  0  0 54  0  0  0
```

Comment: Would there be a way to have the output be something like, 0 58 0 0 0 54 0  0?

Comment: @AdamWarner Updated the post

Comment: Not as simple as I thought the answer was going to be. Very nice and concise, will accept in a minute.